# How to name a routine interruption in the work of some system that is deliberately done in order to find possible weak points?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, terminology

How would you name a routine interruption in the work of some system (let's say a subway or a railroad) that is deliberately done by the workers on a regular basis in order to find some possible weak points in that system that might cause its breakdown?

Comment: "fetch some possble weak points" would be better as "find possible weak points"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That sounds to me like [scheduled maintenance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduled_maintenance):

> a scheduled service visit carried out by a competent and suitable agent, to ensure that an item of equipment is operating correctly and to therefore avoid any unscheduled breakdown and downtime.

Comment: This could also be "routine maintenance" or "preventative maintenance". These modifiers serve to distinguish this type of fixing from "emergency repair" which would neither be scheduled, nor routine nor preventative,

Comment: @JohnSatta * ahem * *preventive*

Answer (score 1):

How about [*stress testing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing)?

> *Stress testing* is a form of testing that is used to determine the stability of a given system or entity. It involves testing beyond normal operational capacity, often to a breaking point, in order to observe the results. Stress testing may have a more specific meaning in certain industries, such as *fatigue testing* for materials.

Comment: Is stress testing not something done before the whole system is launched? Is it really a procedure performed repeatedly on a regular basis after the launch?

Comment: Frankly, I dunno. That's certainly the term that springs to my mind, and I don't see a reason why it couldn't be a regular thing, but then again I am not in a position to comment on how (and whether at all) it is being used in the railroad operation business.

Comment: Testing is not something that should interrupt normal operation of a system.

Comment: @CesarGon: Normally any kind of downtime is bad but sometimes you have to interrupt the system to properly test or maintain it. Like, if you want to test the emergency features on an airplane, would you do it while carrying passengers?

Comment: @Shiny: I know, I know. ;-)